# MC33883 how many transistors can be connected on the high/low side and what PWM frequency to use?

Tags: pwm, dc-motor, h-bridge

I am developing a 24 V 25 A DC-motor driver, using the MC33883 driver and WMK060N10HGS transistors, 4 pieces per side, and powerful Schottky’s diodes to suppress EMF. There is a working prototype. Measurements that are still available (at PWM 20 kHz): Turning on the high side to 10V 500 ns, then after some time it rises to almost 15V (14.5). It turns off in 1.8 us (there are no diodes on the gate, I will put it later, it may close faster). Actually questions:

1. What frequency should I choose for correct operation?
2. What is the acceptable opening/closing time of transistors and at what PWM frequency?
3. Should I reduce voltage? (acceptable voltage of the Vcc2 is 28 V; voltage of the battery is 28 V)
4. Maybe there will be some other recommendations or can you recommend a more powerful driver?

[image]

**Driver Prototype**

[image]

**H-bridge (Picture from the datasheet)**

[image]
**The power part of my H-bridge with additional mosfets**

[MC33883 Datasheet](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/MC33883.pdf)

[WMK060N10HGS Datasheet](https://www.way-on.com/files.html?id=25054)

[MBR10100CT Datasheet](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/products_inactive_data/MBR10100CT-MBRF10100CT.pdf)

Comment: Where is the definitely needed schematic? What do you mean by "shoulder"? Please explain this term: *collector motor driver*.

Comment: The main circuit is taken from the datasheet. "shoulder" - high-side and low-side, collector motor driver - Driver DC motor

Comment: Welcome! Please inline a schematic.

Comment: By not even _linking_ to the datasheet you're making it annoyingly difficult for people to help you. It doesn't look like an official Motorola PCB.

Comment: Do you mean turn-off in 1.8us? If you have a slow turn-off at 1.8ms, then you couldn't modulate any faster than a few hundred Hz or so. One should probably not make the the sum of turn-on and turn-off time more than maybe half to a quarter of the shortest requires pulse length, otherwise most of the power is being dissipated in the transistors.

Comment: Please look at my post again, I tried to make it as correct as possible. Thank you.

Comment: **"What frequency should I choose for correct operation?"**  What does the motor spec sheet say?

Comment: Motor model: MY1020ZXFH-450W24V (MY1020Z).
Rated otput power 450W.
Rated speed 3000rpm.
Full load current 24A.
Rated torque 1.45Nm.
More complete information could not be found.